# How to set Unicode character as Content of Label in the code-behind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unicode

I have a Label that looks the following:

```
<Label Name="FalsePositiveInput" Content="&#x2713;">
```

This works but how can I do it in the code-behind? I tried this but obviously it's not working:

```
FalsePositiveInput.Content = "&#x2713;";
```

The character i want to display is a check mark symbol

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use a unicode escape sequence, rather than a character entity:

```
FalsePositiveInput.Content = "\u2713";
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use the ``\u`` escape sequence.  Worked for me, using FontAwesome in VS.

Answer (score 18):

+1 for 一二三

Just one remark: If you want to use extended Unicode, you need to use not `\u`, but `\U` and 8 characters, e.g. to display left-pointing magnifying glass (1F50D http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f50d/index.htm) you need to use:

```
this.MyLabel.Text = "\U0001F50D";
```

Alternatively as was suggested you can paste right into your source code and then you don't need comments like `"//it is a magnifying glass"`, but then you will have to save your source code in Unicode, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I totally agree, I wanted to make it a comment, but I have a new account here and it didn't allow me to comment.

Answer (score 4):

Return Check symbol
This works in the code-behind and report :)

```
public static string FormatValue(object value, string format)
    {
        if (value == null) return "";           

        Type type = value.GetType();

        if (type == typeof(bool))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
            {
                if ((bool)value)
                {
                    return "Yes";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "No";
                }
            }
            else
            {                    
                if ((bool)value)
                {
                    return ((char)0x221A).ToString(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }


        return value.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If the character is constant and know at compile time, I'm pretty sure you can simply write the character as-is in the source code file, without encoding it as HTML entity. In other words, source files can be Unicode-encoded and Visual Studio will take care of that (or at least it does for me).

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Dario,

If it's a check mark symbol you need just copy it from another source into your code.

Easily found on wikipedia for instance.

Here they are :
✓, ✔, ☑

Taken from :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark

Answer (score 0):

just copy and past caractor from here

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Arrows

then your text in xamal looks like this

```
<Button Text="← Bla bla" >
```